# Как реализовать связи между разными базами MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли создать связи между двумя и более базами данных?

Допустим, чтобы таблица **А** в базе **А** имела отношение к таблице **Б**, базы **Б**.

Comment: какого рода отношение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужен внешний ключ для поля из таблицы с другой базы данных - то да

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database_a.table_a`(
ID INT,
**ID_REF** INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (**ID_REF**) REFERENCES database_b.table_b(ID) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON    DELETE CASCADE
);

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете ссылаться на таблицу в базе используя полное имя - `A.A` и `Б.Б` соответсвенно